# Hiding an element in WebView in Android as it is loaded (or preventing it from loading altogether)

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am loading a URL in a WebView in Android, and I want to hide an element that appears near the top of a very long page. Now, I am currently using javascript to hide the element in the onPagefinished method as below:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('to-hide')[0].style.display='none';})()");
}
```

However, this element is near the top of a page, and my page is fairly long, so this code doesn't execute till maybe 10 seconds in. Now I need to be able to hide this element as soon as it appears, or preferably block it from being loaded altogether, because having it visible causes serious interface issues.

Any idea how can I do this?

(BTW putting the same code in onPageStarted doesn't seem to work since I believe the element is not loaded at that point).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured out the best way to do this was to use JSoup. I loaded the document, and them removed the necessary elements, finally loading it into the WebView. There were two concerns that I had that were disproven:

1) I was afraid adding JSoup would bloat up my apk size. This was not true - the size increase was very small.

2) I thought JSoup would not publish to the WebView till it pulled the whole document, but to my pleasant surprise JSoup doesn't wait - it seems it just gets the DOM, removes the elements needed, and then just loads the WebView, allowing the rest of the page to load in the view.

Hopefully this is useful to people trying to do this. There are many examples of such JSoup code here and on the internet so I won't repeat it, but feel free to reach out if anyone wants sample code.